# Error 405: Method not Allowed on POST method

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I try to pass an object to my backend (spring boot), but it doesn't work.
I have other post method and they work. I don't understand what I am missing.

error:

```
XNIO-1 task-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Method Not Allowed: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Front-end (angular):

service:

```
  create(report: IReport): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post<IReport>(this.resourceUrl, report, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

Model:

```
export class Report implements IReport {
  constructor(
    public companiesId?: number[],
    public jobsId?: number[],
    public customersId?: number[],
    public usersId?: number[],
    public dates?: Moment[],
    public projectsId?: number[]
  ) {}
```

Backend:

controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ReportRessource {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportRessource.class);

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private static final String NAME = "report";

    private ReportService reportService;

    public ReportRessource(ReportService reportService) {
        this.reportService = reportService;
    }
```

...

```
@PostMapping("/report}")
@PreAuthorize(
    "hasAnyAuthority(\"" +
    AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN +
    "\"+\"," +
    AuthoritiesConstants.CUSTOMER_ADMIN +
    "\"+\"," +
    AuthoritiesConstants.INSPECTOR +
    "\")"
)

public ResponseEntity<Boolean> createFullReport( @RequestBody ReportDTO report) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
log.debug("REPORTDTO : {}", report);

this.reportService.makeFullReport(report);
return ResponseEntity
    .noContent()
    .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, NAME, report.toString()))
    .build();
```

}

ReportDTO:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ReportDTO {
    private Set<Long> companiesId = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Long> jobsId = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Long> customersId = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Long> usersId = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<LocalDate> dates = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Long> projectsId = new HashSet<>();

    public ReportDTO() {
        // Empty constructor needed for Jackson.
    }
```

I don't now where should I search. Any idea?
Thank you!

EDIT:

Problem => "report}" should be "report"

Comment: are you using springSecurityFilterChain?

Comment: Yes I am, do you have a clue?

Comment: Is the value `"/report}"` in your `PostMapping` copied from your code? Because that closing brace doesn't really belong there.

Comment: Sorry I was blind. Thank you, it was the issue... Shame on me.